# Delete a string in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular7

```
<input placeholder="#hashtags" type="text" (keydown)="backKeyValidation($event)">

 backKeyValidation(evt) {
    let value = evt.target.value ;
    }
```

For Eg-

```
input value = smk #k l#ls #l s# #sde

delete with backspace of #sde till its "#"  of "sde"-- last hash;
after that delete and update input as-  smk #k l#ls #l
```

likewise Rest should get deleted;
Here value is like  `#smk #k l#ls #l s# #s`;
I want to delete last string with # to get deleted character wise then when it reaches to last '#' should delete complete "#'s with other strings"

It means - `delete from "#" to "#"` and update input as well, when backspace key is entered.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vanilla javascript then this is not the way to bind events.

My solution is:

- Separate javascript codes from html file
- Bind an event listener for **keydown**

**Run the snippet and test it:**

```js
const filteredInput = document.getElementById('filtered-input');

filteredInput.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  let value = e.target.value;
  // 8 is keyCode for backspace on windows 
  // or delete button on mac
  if(e.keyCode === 8) {
    //if there is a last hash tage
    // thene delete it with word
    if(value.lastIndexOf("#") !== -1) {
       value = value.slice(0, value.lastIndexOf("#"));
    }
  }
  this.value = value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="filtered-input">
```

This is just a simple example to give you an idea.I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it should delete # to #hash, when the user cursor has reached single last # tag after it has deleted some other strings with last hash( having no other strings with last #), then the above process should start.

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr you have to find cursor position if it is in the end of input the above process well work otherwise if it is not in the end you should implement it the way it deletes the last #hash before of cursor position.
[here is a link to how to find cursor position](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/282/how-to-get-the-current-cursor-position-and-selection-within-a-text-input-or-textarea-in-javascript)